# How to stop VS Code from removing curly brackets from {% ... %} statements when pressing enter?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Nunjucks, a jinja2-based template language and it uses the syntax `{% ... %}`.

In VS Code, the default behavior when I press enter upon using the above syntax is to remove the curly brackets.

[GIF Example](https://i.imgur.com/rDZ3BiU.mp4)

How do I stop this?

Comment: Please add list of your related extensions in vscode

Answer (score 0):

You probably accept the EMET suggest by typing Enter after your closing bracket }.
You could either disable EMET, or maybe change which button accepts a suggestion (for example change it to Shift).
What worked for me was downloading the Better Jinja extention and associating HTML files with this.

Comment: Please add name of your acceptable vscode extension.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the emmet was triggered when you press enter.

I found that installing this [Django extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django) can override the emmet behavior